# differnece between 2 refrence(using Unity & using Microsoft.Practices.Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container

As my Title itself indicates the query. I am using UNity Framework for DI. So some time not sure why the build is failing due to similar name space calls.

My doubt is what is difference between

```
using Unity; 
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
```

e.g. `var container = new UnityContainer();` 
In this case the Unitycontainer is available in both of the name spaces. I am really confused in this context.

Comment: Are you using the Unity3D engine? (IIRC the Unity3D engine uses the `Unity` namespace)

Comment: No , I am using Unit.webApi. where as I found these issues so stuck

Comment: Any help can I get here?